# Make pattern transparent and use it as a mask

Tags: vector, transparency, background, mask, noise

I have an issue with a pattern image (TIFF) that I just cant get around with.
To keep the explanation short, I'll add pictures for reference.

The issue is that I cant re-create this exact same effect. I tried Photoshop but I could only remove the BG and the pattern still had a color be it white or black.

The pattern you see in "Image1" is kind of transparent and every BG color is seen through the pattern. The pattern works kinda like a mask from what I understand.

The pattern image I speak of is "Image2".

I know Multiply Blend Mode would work with extra steps but I need the pattern as a good to go file/image for future use. I vaguely remember that this has been the case before.

**Is there a way to create this this exact same effect in Photoshop or even better in Illustrator as an already good to go file/image?**

Thank you so much in advance!

Edit: Better phrasing for clarification. Added an extra Image.

[image: Image1]

<sup>Click for full size</sup>

[image: Image2]

<sup>Click for full size</sup>

Comment: I doubt that's procedurally-generated noise. It may have even originated as a photo… or several photos. Each coloured segment has its own distinct pattern, none of the noise overlaps the next segment. That allows for each layer to have its own treatment, colour, opacity etc.

Comment: You are absolutely right, tho I can confirm it is just one picture. Forgive me for my inexperience maybe I should rephrase it better. I shouldn‘t have called it noise either more like pattern. I‘ll add some things to better visualise what I mean.

Comment: @Billyker gives a good idea of how to do this, but if you look carefully at your image, you can see that each layer has its own transparency "knocked-out" (as opposed to a single pass as in Billy's example): you can see parts of the white layer's blue texture showing through the ochre color's texture layer and the white knocks out to the blue underlayer. The scale of the texture is different on each color layer as well (I *assume* it is the same texture duplicated and used for all three)

Answer (score 2):

I would use something like a natural paper texture, either one you can find online, or a photograph of a real texture you took yourself.

Place the texture on a layer above your artwork, then you can invert the texture layer, desaturate it, and set the layer blending mode to Lighten.  You can also do a levels adjustment to darken the texture a bit.

You can also experiment with different blending modes such as Color Dodge, perhaps Difference, or Exclusion, etc.

An example

[image]

Here's the same, but with Exclusion as the blend mode.

[image]